# How to access a toplevel entity in ruby, from inside a module which defines the same name

Tags: ruby

Inside a module I have a class named `Process`.

```
module M
  Process= Class.new
  Process::wait(0)
end
```

This raises `NoMethodError`.

How do I access the toplevel `Process` from inside the module? Is this at all possible, without renaiming my class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
::Process.wait(0)
```