# @object = ::tablename.where ( ) in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can any one please explain the below simple statement

```
@object ||= ::Tablename.where (:fieldname => value ).first
```

What is it mean and why `||` is used with `=` and `::` is used before table name ?

Comment: `||=` is used to cached the value in `@object` it's basically doing `@object = .. unless @object` so "Set object to this unless object is already set". `::Tablename` the prefixed `::` is basically doing a top-level class lookup. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334949/how-to-access-a-toplevel-entity-in-ruby-from-inside-a-module-which-defines-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet checks to see if `@object` is `false` or `nil`; if it is, it assigns it the value produced by calling the method named `Tablename` in the top-level namespace.

This is because `||=` means "assign if the value is currently falsey"; and `::` is the scope resolution operator. Often it appears with a class name on the left, as in `Net::HTTP` accessing the `HTTP` constant in the `Net` module. Without a name on the left, it means "in the top-level scope".

Comment: @Ganesh - you're welcome. Remember you can mark the answer as "helpful" by clicking the up arrow; and/or accepting it as "correct" by clicking the green tick. Accepting answers to your questions will help keep people happy to help you in the future!